# Elegant way to destructure array, first n elements and rest

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

I can solve this problem in a few different ways, but I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Take an array

```
let foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Is there a method using array destructuring that would work like thist:

```
split(array, n) =>
  ...

let bar = split(foo, 3)
bar[0] = [1,2,3]
bar[1] = [4,5]
```

I don't know n coming into the problem. I feel like this should be doable with destructuring, but the way I am reading it I do not see how to do so.

Comment: So, you want to split an array into chunks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: @mikemike Not precisely. I want the first piece to be of size 0-n, and a second that is whatever remains, no matter size.

Comment: You'd just use `slice` twice. There's no native `partition` method in js

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with declaring n variables and then merging them into an array, you could use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```
const [a, b, ...rest] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

console.log([a,b], rest);
// expected output: [10,20] [30,40,50]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return array with two arrays. Then you can use destructuring to assign parts to different variables

```
split(array, n) =>
  return [array.slice(0, n), array.slice(n)]

let foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
let [bar, baz] = split(foo, 3)
console.log(bar) // [1,2,3]
console.log(baz) // [4,5]
```

Here is a [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20split(array%2C%20n)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%5Barray.slice(0%2C%20n)%2C%20array.slice(n)%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0Alet%20%5Bbar%2C%20baz%5D%20%3D%20split(foo%2C%203)%0Aconsole.log(bar)%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0Aconsole.log(baz)%20%2F%2F%20%5B4%2C5%5D) where you can try it out